# Subgroup of a Direct Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups and $G\times H$ their direct product.

a) Prove that $\{(x,e) : x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times H$

b) Prove that $\{(x,x) : x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$

I don't know where to begin. Do you still have to prove the resulting subgroup is closed under the operation or just closed under inverses.

Comment: you have to prove both....

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to prove a subset $K \subset M$ is a subgroup of a group $M$ is the [Subgroup test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test) : If $a,b \in K$, then show that $ab^{-1} \in K$.

Consider $K := \{(x,e) : x\in G\} \subset G\times H =: M$. Then, for $a = (x_1, e), b = (x_2,e) \in K$, note that
$$
ab^{-1} = (x_1x_2^{-1},e) \qquad\text{ (why?)}
$$
Hence, $ab^{-1} \in K$, and so $K < M$.

Can you try the same thing for $K:= \{(x,x) : x\in G\} \subset G\times G =: M$

Comment: If i am using the two step subgroup test can I use similar steps and say ab is (x1x2,e)∈K and a^-1 is (x^-1,e)∈K therefore it is a subgroup? For the other part to the question, K:={(x,x):x∈G}⊂G×G=:M my instinct would be to let a=(x1,x2) and b=(x3,x4) then ab would then be (x1x3,x2x4)∈K and a^-1 is (x1^-1,x2^-1)∈K. Am I using proper reasoning?

Comment: Well, you need $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_3=x_4$ for this to make sense, right?

Comment: If i make that distinction known then it would be correct? With that then x1x3=x2x4 in ab which would make sense and same for a^-1.