# Show that $H \times\{1_K\}$ is a normal subgroup of $H \times K$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

> If $H$, $K$ are two groups, show that $H \times \{1_K\}$, $\{1_H\} \times K$ are normal subgroups of $H \times K$. Identify the corresponding quotient groups.

Is the $\times$ a direct product? I really have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Yes $\times$ is a direct product. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525454/subgroup-of-a-direct-product

Comment: Ah. And for finding quotient groups?

Answer (score 1):

For the quotient group $H\times K/H\times \{1_K\}$, consider the surjective homomorphism
$$
\pi : H\times K \to K, \text{ given by } (x,y) \mapsto x
$$
and use the first isomorphism theorem. Now do something similar for $H\times K/\{1_H\}\times K$

Comment: Ugh I quickly discovered I don't know what I'm doing. Is it just H x K / 1 x K?